# "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)" from git status

Tags: git, repository, clone, git-clone, git-status

This command works to get the files and compile them:

```
git clone a-valid-git-url
```

for example:

```
git clone git://cfdem.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/cfdem/liggghts
```

However, `git status` (or any other git command) then gives the above `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The checked-out code is in the `liggghts` directory.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You have to actually cd into the directory first:

```
$ git clone git://cfdem.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/cfdem/liggghts
Cloning into 'liggghts'...
remote: Counting objects: 3005, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2141/2141), done.
remote: Total 3005 (delta 1052), reused 2714 (delta 827)
Receiving objects: 100% (3005/3005), 23.80 MiB | 2.22 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1052/1052), done.

$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
$ cd liggghts/
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Comment: You also get this error when git hoses it's own .git directory. I did a pull, and saw the message "Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance." I then tried to do some more operations, only getting OP's error message. My .git folder is still there, but git has somehow corrupted it. Running `git init` fixed the problem.

Comment: How stupid I am. Trying git status before going to the directory :)
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 34):

I just got this message and there is a very simple answer before trying the others. At the parent directory, type `git init`

This will initialize the directory for git. Then `git add` and `git commit` should work.

Comment: Before or after the clone? Would this create a new git repo?  How would this work with the existing git repo and history that was cloned?  What happens to the original `remote` setting under this arrangement?

Comment: This is the git equivalent of forgetting a semi-colon, gosh I feel so stupid 

Comment: 2023 Update: `git init` will show a message that the current git repository as been 'reinitialized' but will NOT affect files (from the clone) or the `remote` settings.  However it is irelevant as the actual OP issue is still that the user needs to `cd` into the directory to do this

Answer (score 15):

In my case, was an environment variable `GIT_DIR`, which I added to access faster.

This also broke all my local repos in SourceTree :(

Comment: export GIT_DIR=path/to/dir/.git

Comment: omg.. I accidentally introduced a variable with exact same name in my scripts, and got the problem

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes its because of ssh. So you can use this:

```
git clone https://cfdem.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/cfdem/liggghts
```

instead of:

```
git clone git://cfdem.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/cfdem/liggghts
```

Comment: I was getting the error just trying to clone a repo to my local machine. I switched FROM using https:// TO git:// and it was successfully cloned. Thx for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I used git clone git@....xyz.git and it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

If Existing Project Solution is planned to move on TSF in VS Code:

open Terminal and run following commands:

1. **Initialize** git in that folder (root Directory)

   `git init`
2. **Add** Git

   `git add .`
3. **Link** your TSf/Git to that Project  -  {url} replace with your git address

   `git remote add origin {url}`
4. **Commit** those Changes:

   `git commit -m "initial commit"`
5. **Push** - I pushed code as version1 you can use any name for your branch

   `git push origin HEAD:Version1`

Answer (score 5):

This error got resolved when I tried initialising the git using **git init** . It worked

Answer (score 4):

in my case, i had the same problem while i try any git -- commands (eg git status) using windows  cmd. so what i do is after installing  git for window https://windows.github.com/
in the environmental variables, add the class path of the git on the "PATH" varaiable. usually the git will installed on `C:/user/"username"/appdata/local/git/bin` add this on the PATH in the environmental variable

and one more thing on the cmd go to your git repository or cd to where your clone are on your window usually they  will be stored on the documents under github

```
cd Document/Github/yourproject
```

after that you can have any git commands

Answer (score 4):

```
git clone https://github.com/klevamane/projone.git
Cloning into 'projone'...
remote: Counting objects: 81, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
remote: Total 81 (delta 13), reused 78 (delta 13), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (81/81), done.
```

you have to "cd projone"

then you can check status.

---

One reason why this was difficult to notice at first, i because you created a folder with the same name already in your computer and that was where you cloned the project into, so you have to change directory again

---

Answer (score 3):

I had another problem. I was in a git directory, but got there through a symlink. I had to go into the directory directly (i.e. not through the symlink) then it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the original repository was a bare one.

So, I had to type (in windows):

```
mkdir   dest
cd dest
git init
git remote add origin a\valid\yet\bare\repository
git pull origin master
```

To check if a repository is a bare one:

```
git rev-parse --is-bare-repository
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, after you clone the repo you need to cd ***(change your current directory)*** to the new cloned folder

```
git clone https://User_Name@bitbucket.org/Repo_Name.git

cd Repo_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

for me; I had been having problems getting the solution to clean properly in Visual Studio, so I did a wildcard delete of any directories called bin, obj...
.git has a directory called /objects which was caught up in the delete.
I discovered when doing a kdiff of the working clone and the broken one.
oops :)

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly got an error like in any directory I tried to run any git command from:

`fatal: Not a git repository: /Users/me/Desktop/../../.git/modules/some-submodule`

For me, turned out I had a hidden file `.git` on my Desktop with the content:

`gitdir: ../../.git/modules/some-module`

Removed that file and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem from my office network. 
i **use** this command but its not working for me
**url,
 so like this:
before**
`$ git clone https://gitlab.com/omsharma/Resume.git`

**After** i Use this URL : `$ git clone https://my_gitlab_user@gitlab.com/omsharma/Resume.git`

try It.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was dealing with github workflow jobs and simply forgot to checkout the repo before my step. Adding pre requisite step `actions/checkout@v2` resolved the issue.