# github workflow - fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: git, merge, repository

I have a master branch and a dev branch for current development(local working copy). I need to merge changes from master onto my dev branch. Prior to merge I ran git stash and discovered the following error:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

To investigate this error I ran the following commands:
`git status`
`git branch`
`git remote -v`. All produced the same error `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I also tried resetting the origin of my branch `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Connexions/oer.exports.git` which produces the same result:  `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I cannot commit any changes from my local working directory onto my dev branch either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to correct this issue.

Comment: Make sure your current directory has a `.git` folder?

Comment: What displays `$ ls .git` in this directory?

Comment: I decided to make a backup of my branch, reclone, pull the branch and paste the files back. This resolved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)" from git status](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961600/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-from-git-status)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get that error message is to somehow *not* be in the git repo working tree.
See "[After `git clone` I get a “ `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` ” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961600/after-git-clone-i-get-a-fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-dire)" as an illustration.

It can also be cause because of a `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable being set to the wrong path.
Or it is seen in wrappers using git repo like [`rvm`](https://rvm.io/) (see [this thread](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1031) for example)

In both case, resetting the situation in a new clone (which you did) usually is a good way to fix the situation.

Answer (score 17):

Check the following file:

- `your_repo_dir/.git/HEAD`

If this content seems corrupted, this is the issue. I had the similar issue and I fixed it by replacing the content of the HEAD file with the git commit hash of the last commit from selected branch.

Commit hashes could be found under the `.git/logs/refs/heads  and branch_name_file`

I hope it helps.

Comment: This was the solution when I ran into this problem. The HEAD file had disappeared.

Comment: This worked in our case, too. Our code dir is mounted on a mac from a VirtualBox guest via samba and frequently after waking up from sleep we get this error. The .git/HEAD is empty, and restoring it with a legit sha fixes the problem. There was also a leftover .git/index.lock that had to be removed.

Answer (score 3):

I had this error after having problems with visual studio git plugin.

The solution was to rename `my_repo_dir/.git/HEAD.lock` to `my_repo_dir/.git/HEAD`

Looks like something crashed after locking the head file and that killed the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem after I tried to push the branch to remote from Visual Studio. I renamed .git/HEAD.lock to .git/HEAD after checking its content. Now it works fine.