# .git folder on client's machine, but git not installed. What does it mean?

Tags: git, github, version-control, installation

Working with a new client, with poor previous documentation, I found a .git folder in their site files. But when I check for a git install via terminal with `git --version` I get "command not found", so I reason git is not installed.

Any ideas what this might mean? For example, how was the .git folder created? Is there a GUI that uses .git without a terminal git version?

**Update:**
Copied files over to my local machine (that has git) and ran `git remote show origin` to try and back-trace what they were doing before. But I get the following message: `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I've checked questions and answers at the following and they aren't applicable :

- [Receiving "fatal: Not a git repository" when attempting to remote add a Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630704/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-when-attempting-to-remote-add-a-git-repo)
- ["fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)" from git status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961600/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-from-git-status)
- ["fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)" from git status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961600/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-from-git-status)

Comment: Could you share why this is being down-voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess is that it's a combination of (a) not obviously being a question that relates to software development, and (b) not providing enough information for anyone to usefully help you. None of us has a crystal ball that can tell us how that .git directory got created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What more info can I provide to say why git is saying that there is no repository?

You can compare you .git folder that you have copied to a .git folder created when you do:

```
git init newRepo
```

Compare the content of `newRepo/.git` and your copied `.git` and see if there are elements missing which would explain why this .git folder isn't recognized as a git repo folder.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the "sites" directory was moved from another computer that did have git installed on it.

You did not provide enough information to say why git is saying that there is no repository. Maybe the .git directory got corrupted. Perhaps the directory is from an older version of git that is no longer recognized. Maybe you are accidentally running git from a different directory.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What more info can I provide to say why git is saying that there is no repository? Or how to check if the .git directory got corrupted?