# "ELIFECYCLE" Error after running 'npm install && npm run dev'

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npm-install

I'm trying to create an imageboard by building from cloned github repositories. I'm using npm for this, but for reasons I'm not quite sure of, I'm met with errors that I will post below.

I've tried to alleviate this by running: `npm cache clean --force`, followed by: `rm -rf node_modules`, and then followed by: `rm -rf package-lock.json`.

After all of this, I ran `npm install && npm run dev` once more, and yet still, I was met with the exact same errors.

Initial commands used:
`git clone https://gitgud.io/millchan/Millchan.git`
`npm install && npm run dev`

First off, I do: `git clone https://gitgud.io/millchan/Millchan.git`, and then I do: `cd ~/millchan`. The "millchan" folder is the one created from cloning the repositories.

Then, afterwards...

- After running `npm install`: https://pastebin.com/kus7p6Cy
  (had to post on pastebin because stackoverflow's AI thinks it's spam)
- After running `npm run dev`: https://pastebin.com/KbvggQP2

Comment: can you add  the script part of your package.json to see what 'dev' does or tries to do?

Comment: @rebecca `"dev": "webpack --mode development --config webpack.config.js --watch --env.development",`

Comment: ah well. i guess i need the webpack config too, also could you include them in your post for better formatting? 
the error message from dev is suggesting that your project "should" be a git project or rather it fails because it's not, see ln 9 from your second pastebin

Comment: @rebecca Hello again, and thank you for your assistance so far. Unfortunately, I really can't include much else in my post due to character limit, and due to the fact that the site's AI will most likely render my pastes as spam. webpack.config.js: -> https://pastebin.com/RUWDBXTA

Comment: is the project your currently working in a git-project? otherwise i think this part `let commitHash = require('child_process').execSync('git rev-parse --short HEAD').toString();`in the beginning of your webpack.config is causing the error. maybe try removing it and see what happens?

Comment: according to this Error: Command failed: git rev-parse --short HEAD
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: @rebecca My project is a git-project, yes. Also, after removing `let commitHash = require('child_process').execSync('git rev-parse --short HEAD').toString();` and running the rest of the commands again, I'm still met with the exact same errors.

Comment: ah shoot, i guess that would've been too easy. what node version are you running? maybe there are some incompatabilities...?

Comment: @rebecca I'm running node version 12.6.0.

Comment: did you also add " the gnu compiler collection for c++, which is gcc-c++ for fedora or g++ for debian." per the project? i'm sorry, i'm just pulling on straws here... another suggestion would be to delete everything and make a new clean copy and try again :/

Comment: @rebecca I've installed g++, yes. Also, unfortunately, I've reinstalled everything before, to no avail. But, I'll try again this time. Thank you for helping me so far. I'm always open to more assistance if you ever come up with more ideas.

Comment: unfortunately, i have no real ideas left, wish i could've helped you more. you could raise an issue with the original project, maybe they can help you out or encountered something similar before, otherwise, no clue :/

Comment: hey, i researched a little more, especially regarding the first git error. i still think the problem lays there... could you try a `git init` in your project folder?
see [here](https://errorcodespro.com/4-fixes-for-fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-git/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961600/fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-from-git-status/11961642)

Comment: @rebecca Extremely late, but your last comment completely solved my issue. Thank you very much.