# Devops pipeline to copy output into Repo

Tags: azure-devops

I'm looking at creating a DevOps pipeline to build a .NET project within a repository and then to copy the output of that build into another folder in the repository.

So I have something like this

```
Root
    CommonFiles
    Project 1
    Project 2
    NetProject
```

So I want to build the project inside `NetProject` and copy the resultant DLL to the `CommonFiles` folder. The other projects will then use that DLL when they are build. The other projects that reference the DLL are VB6 projects, hence not using nuget or other package managers.

I can't see any variables or such like to use in the pipeline to copy the file to the correct location. Does anyone have any ideas or am I missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Devops pipeline to copy output into Repo

By default the source files are checked out to the `Build.SourcesDirectory` (e.g :  Directory: `D:\a\1\s`), it can be considered as a temporary git repository.

To resolve this issue, you need to use the copy task to copy the files from the output folder of the `NetProject` to the `CommonFiles`.

After that all the files still in the `Build.SourcesDirectory` instead of our repo.

We need use the git command to push those files to the reppo, like:

```
git add Test.txt

git commit -m "Add a test file"

git push https://PAT@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/xxx HEAD:master
```

You could check [my another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990634/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-git/63006319#63006319) for some more details.

**Note:** Please note that you need to [Grant version control permissions to the build service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#grant-version-control-permissions-to-the-build-service) and enable [Allow scripts to access the system token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#allow-scripts-to-access-the-system-token).

[image]