# How to save file from Azure CLI output to my DevOps Repo

Tags: azure, azure-cli

So I have a pipeline and want to save the output from Azure CLI to my Repo so l can use later on.

I am using out-file but not sure how to point it to a folder in my repo

Comment: Can you share the code you tried so far? @John Smith

Comment: Get-LogicAppTemplate @parameters | Out-File test.json # I want the out-file pointing to my project repo file location

Comment: Where is your repo located. In pipeline repo or downloaded to local? @John Smith

Comment: Yes that is correct,  TicketTool/_git/Ticket?path=/LogicAppTicket

Comment: Is this your relative pipeline repo path? @John Smith

Comment: yes, so l want to put download the file and put in that folder via Azure CLI

Comment: You can achieve in a way that there is an option of importing & exporting a pipeline repo to other locations. Export a pipeline into Az CLI directory and simple download the file to the pipeline repo path in AzCLI directly. @John smith

Comment: apologises l should have said l have getting a .json from AzurePortal and then wanting to push that to the repo so l can re-use

Comment: Will work on it and update. @John Smith

Comment: You need to use out-file with a pipe operator. After downloading it, you can easily push it to Devops repo using git commands. @John Smith

Comment: Updated the answer. It should work for you.  @John Smith

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Out-File` to download the file directly, like you did. I tried to retrieve the logic app template as shown.

```
Get-Logicapptemplate -ResourceGroup xxxxx -LogicApp "rith00" -SubscriptionId "xxxxx" | Out-File -FilePath /home/madugula/samplejson.json
```

[image]

[image]

*After downloading the file locally, you can commit and push it to your DevOps repository using below Git commands.*

```
git add "locally downloaded file path"
```

After adding the file path, I used git commit -m to save the changes with a message.

```
git commit -m "xxx"
```

Now, I used below git push command origin with the branch name to push the file into Devops repository branch.

```
git push origin <Devops branch name>
```

*Reference:*

Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67882274/19785512) by @Leo Liu for the relevant issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, only issue I see with that is when I finally do it via pipeline CD cant have a users file path hardcoded, want a streamline process that you get the .json file and save directly to the repo

Comment: To make it as a streamline process, you need to follow few steps in Devops pipeline. You need to create a CLI task and output the json file. And then [publish the json as an artifact](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/blob/main/docs/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts.md#publish-and-download-pipeline-artifacts) by creating a Powershell task. After all, you can be able to access the .json as a downloaded pipeline artifact in your repo. This streamline process is a bit lengthy I would say. @JohnSmith